# Control an app via Voice Commands

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I am thinking about possibilities how to control an app via voice commands - navigation between pages, call commands etc. while an app runs.

There is `SpeechRecognizer` which is basically what I need, however, there is timeout option `SpeechRecognizer.Timeouts.InitialSilenceTimeout` - default value is 5s. If I want to use this approach should I set up very big timeout in order to listen all voice commands while an app runs or is there any different solution? Are there any "side" problems?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use continuous recognition. It will never stop listening until you tell it to do so.
There are several 
[samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis/cs) here to help you start with speech recognition / synthesis.